# Facebook PHP SDK session_start() error on live domain, but no error on localhost (using same WordPress environment on both)

Tags: php, facebook

I am facing an error that I can't fix for hours now. Everything looks fine on localhost. but on my live domain I am getting session error. Here is some information that may help you give me any idea about the error.

- I am using Facebook PHP SDK
- I am using WordPress latest version on both, localhost and live domain
- I am using the same files, exact copy of application on both localhost and live domain
- On localhost, no errors are returned.
- On live domain I get that error:

  Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/vantaget/public_html/wordpress/sofashare/wp-content/themes/sofashare/header.php:6) in /home/vantaget/public_html/wordpress/sofashare/wp-content/themes/sofashare/lib/facebook/facebook.php on line 37

Here is how I implemented the facebook sdk.

First I put this in my functions.php file to retrieve error:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

I include the library:

require_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/lib/facebook/facebook.php';

And in the functions file this is the function:

```
function sofa_include($lib) {
    global $sofa, $user;
    if ($lib == 'facebook') {

    // new facebook call
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $sofa['fbappid'],
        'secret' => $sofa['fbappsecret'],
    ));

    // get facebook user
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // get user profile
    if ($user) {
      try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

?>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {

    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {

    });
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>

<?php
    }
}
```

Now in my header.php file I do this to include facebook sdk

```
<?php sofa_include('facebook'); ?>
```

Everything works fine on localhost, with error report set to ALL. But on my live domain i always get the session_start headers sent error. What could be wrong?

Comment: do you call session_start before or after you do the sofa_include() ?

Comment: The session_start() is called first when sofa_include('facebook') is called. The problem goes away if I move that line in header to the top . before <html> but the problem is that this function output JS sdk and javascript of facebook library.

Comment: It is really "stupid" to give me -1 for this question. Clearly someone with nonsense and brain. I have researched solution for 2 hours+ and it is NOT a duplicate question.

Comment: so the declaration of session_start() is before you call sofa_include() or after. i didn't understand your previous comment. I'm interested in the exact calling order of those 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

it's probable that you are outputing that facebook javascript code before the session starts, which leads to your problem. Maybe your local server had output buffering enabled by default or something and the production doesn't